# Validar numero negativo y positivo en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de validar un input que solo pueda agregar números positivos, negativos, cero, con o sin punto decimal, ya conseguí que solo permite agregar valores positivos, cero y con o sin punto decimal pero no permite los negativos (el símbolo -), uso el siguiente código

```js
function validarCantidad(evt, input) {
        // Backspace = 8, Enter = 13, ‘0′ = 48, ‘9′ = 57, ‘.’ = 46
        var key = window.Event ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        var chark = String.fromCharCode(key);
        var tempValue = input.value + chark;
        if (key >= 48 && key <= 57) {
            if (filter(tempValue) === false) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            if (key == 8 || key == 13 || key == 0) {
                return true;
            } else if (key == 45 || key == 46) {
                if (filter(tempValue) === false) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    function filter(__val__) {
        //alert(__val__);
        var preg = /^([0-9]+\.?[0-9]{0,2})$/;
    if (preg.test(__val__) === true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

```html
<input id="cantidad" name="cantidad" type="number" onkeypress="return validarCantidad(event,this);" />
```

He intentado agregar a la validación `/^([-]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]{0,2})$/` pero no permite el símbolo negativo (-).

También probé el siguiente código que encontré aquí:

```
function FormatNumber(event) {
    var dec = $(this).data('decimal');
    var aux = "([+-]?[0-9])([0-9]{" + dec + "})$";
    var expReg = new RegExp(aux);
    $(event.target).val(function (index, value) {
        return value.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(expReg, '$1.$2').replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ",");
    });
}
```

Este si permite agregar el símbolo negativo (-) pero el problema que para el primer carácter agregar cualquiera y valida hasta el segundo.

Espero me puedan apoyar

Comment: No te sirve alguna librería? O debes hacerlo con JavaScript puro? Para que no hagas re-trabajo digo yo

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera me gustaría nativo aunque estoy abierto a usar alguna librería y tal vez me ayude con otras validaciones, cual podría ser?

Comment: [iMask](https://imask.js.org/) podría servir. Simplemente configurando el input puedes validar todo lo que necesitas (sólo positivos, sólo negativos, valor mínimo, valor máximo, etc)

Comment: No estás *validando*, estás evitando que el usuario introduzca ciertos caracteres, usando el evento `keypress`. Puedo introducir un carácter no numérico en tu elemento `input` copiando y pegando, por lo cual lo que tu llamas *validación* no funciona. No es prudente, desde el punto de vista de experiencia de usuario, evitar que se introduzcan caracteres en un elemento `input`. Debes **validar** el texto introducido una vez el usuario termine de interactuar con el elemento, ya sea mediante un clic en un botón o cuando el elemento pierde el foco (`onblur`). Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras pero que ventaja le da validar un texto introducido por el usuario, si el input en sí sólo debería aceptar ciertos carácteres? como un input que sirva para validar DNI con series numéricas, minúsculas, mayúsculas, etc. No le veo lógica, entregarle al browser un trabajo que - para mí - es innecesario, siendo que existen librerías que internamente poseen funciones que ayudan a esas validaciones. Me causa curiosidad tu punto, posiblemente estés analizando algo que pasé por alto :O

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera estoy probando el demo y creo que funciona para lo que necesito

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera, la sobrecarga la pone la librería, en mi opinión. La validación HTML5 (nativa) es más que suficiente en estos casos, sin soluciones mágicas de terceros. Una validación de un campo numérico no necesita mucho código Javascript, el campo sólo requiere a lo sumo un par de atributos y lo demás se hace con CSS. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras pero acaso apoyaste para hacerlo con HTML5?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera este es (entre algunas otros) un motivo sobre el que me baso para decir que [es mejor *validar* que *prevenir*](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/56290/text-field-validation-vs-prevention). Igual es un tema de opiniones, pero en general, cuando hablamos de [UX](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experiencia_de_usuario), es mejor la *validación*. Saludos

Comment: @MRDev si consideras que te he *tratado del asco*, puedes reportar mis comentarios para que sean revisados por moderadores y se determine si mis acciones violan el Código de Conducta y me acarreen una sanción. Disculpa si te he ofendido de alguna manera, no ha sido mi intención. No veo cómo te he criticado, sólo he apuntado donde está (en mi opinión) el error. Te di una respuesta argumentada, si no es lo que buscas o necesitas significa que no comprendí por completo tu pregunta, un error común que cualquiera puede cometer. Mis respuestas van dirigidas a una mayor audiencia, no sólo al OP.

Comment: @MauricioContreras solo pedí ayudar y lo único que hiciste fue criticar pero no hubo nada de ayuda. Pero bueno,  solo por rango te darán preferencia.

Comment: @MRDev no hay preferencias por rango, se ha visto a usuarios de 7k haciendo cosas malas y se los ha sancionado. Si crees que algo infringe el código de conducta reportalo

Comment: _Las críticas son buenas cuando son constructivas_ (que es lo que claramente se ve en los comentarios). Un paseo por el [código de conducta](/conduct) no viene nada mal.

Answer (score 2):

Tal como digo en [mi comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/466510/validar-numero-negativo-y-positivo-en-javascript?noredirect=1#comment830571_466510), no estás realmente *validando* la entrada del usuario, sólo estás evitando que el mismo introduzca ciertos caracteres.

[HTML5](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) nos provee de una rica gama de elementos y API's para realizar esta tarea, sin necesidad de recurrir a librerías externas y usando únicamente Javascript Nativo y CSS.

Por ejemplo, la siguiente validación se realiza sobre un elemento [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) de tipo [`number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number).

```js
let numberInput = document.getElementById('num');

numberInput.addEventListener('blur', e => {
  numberInput.setCustomValidity('');
  numberInput.reportValidity();
});

numberInput.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  if(numberInput.validity.badInput) {
    numberInput.setCustomValidity('Sólo valores numéricos');
  } else {
    numberInput.setCustomValidity('');
  }
});
```

```css
input:invalid {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<label for="num">Introduzca un valor numérico:</label>
<input name="num" id="num" type="number" step="any">
```

Como se observa, realizo la validación cuando el elemento pierde el foco (evento `blur`). Se utiliza Javascript para añadir el manejador de evento y CSS para darle un color de fondo al elemento cuando el mismo tiene la pseudo clase [`:invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid).

También se observa que no se utiliza ningún patrón de expresión regular (`pattern`) ni en el elemento como atributo (los elementos `<input>` de tipo `number` no implementan el atributo `pattern`), ni en Javascript. La [API de validación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Constraint_validation) de HTML5 se encarga de esto por nosotros.

La validación es superada si el valor introducido en el elemento `<input>` se puede convertir en un valor numérico válido en Javascript. Eso incluye cualquier entero o flotante, sea negativo o positivo.

En el elemento utilizo el valor `any` para el atributo [`step`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#step), esto me permite indicar que no importa la cantidad de dígitos decimales (tenga o no tenga), siempre que el valor introducido se pueda convertir en un valor numérico válido, la validación será superada.

Recuerda que las expresiones de tipo exponencial son valores numéricos válidos, por ejemplo:

```js
12e3
-2.34e-1
```

Por lo cual un valor de ese estilo introducido en nuestro elemento `<input>` será validado como correcto.

Si no deseas que se introduzcan este tipo de cadenas, entonces debes usar un elemento tipo [`text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text) y utilizar la validación sobre un patrón de expresión regular, por ejemplo:

```js
let numberInput = document.getElementById('num');

numberInput.addEventListener('blur', e => {
  numberInput.setCustomValidity('');
  numberInput.reportValidity();
});

numberInput.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  if(numberInput.validity.patternMismatch) {
    numberInput.setCustomValidity('Sólo valores numéricos');
  } else {
    numberInput.setCustomValidity('');
  }
});
```

```css
input:invalid {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<label for="num">Introduzca un valor numérico:</label>
<input name="num" id="num" type="text" pattern="^([\-]?[0-9]*[\.]?[0-9]+)$">
```

Nuevamente estoy utilizando la API de validación de HTML5, esta vez sobre un campo de tipo texto, con un patron de expresión regular como el siguiente:

```js
^([\-]?[0-9]*[\.]?[0-9]+)$
```

En el cual estoy indicando que la cadena debe empezar por un signo negativo (sólo 1 o ninguno) seguida de caracteres numéricos que se pueden repetir de cero a *n* veces, seguido de un punto decimal opcional (0 o uno) y debe terminar con valores numéricos (1 o más).

Como puedes observar, en esta validación no se permiten entradas con valores exponenciales.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Excelente explicación, hoy aprendí algo nuevo y voy a tratar de aplicarlo en mis proyectos, a veces uso demasiadas validaciones en Javascript que, a final de cuentas, el navegador ya podría tenerlas consideradas.

Comment: @MRDev, te recomiendo probar esos códigos agregando el evento `input` con las mismas instrucciones de `blur`, en cuanto el usuario teclea un caracter no permitido, verá el mensaje de error.